# regex to match "number,URL"

Tags: regex

I am not experienced with regex and lost whole day trying to match this:

343,SOME_URL
43555,SOME_URL

I need expression to match number and "," so I can cut it something like

343,SOME_URL to become only SOME_URL

Comment: What language? Should work if you replace `\d+,` with an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Use `regex`:

`[0-9]+,` or `\d+,`

and replace it with empty string (`""`).

Comment: Thanks so much! You saved me another day:)